# Change css class with JQuery \ Watermark

Tags: jquery, css, class, addclass, removeclass

My application is trying to show a text watermark in a textbox on a form, but I don't want to touch the actual value of the box. So, I'm trying to use a background image with the watermark text, using classes;

```
    .watermarkon input
   {
        background-image: url('../forms/images/TypeNameWatermark.png');
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
   }

    .watermarkoff input
   {
        background-image: none;
   }
```

I'm setting the textboxes CssClass="watermarkon" in the form, and when such an element is clicked, I'd like to remove the "watermarkon" and replace with "watermarkoff" or even just remove the existing class. I've tried a ton of different attempts at the Syntax, and though I can capture the click event fine, the page never seems to update the element's CSS. Here is my latest attempt:

```
     jQuery(document).ready(
         function() {
             jQuery(".watermarkon input").click(function(event) {
                 jQuery(this).removeClass("watermarkon").addClass("watermarkoff");

             });
         }
     );
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing - why I can't seem to get the CSS change to update the live web page?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are using a wrong selector. Answer from Alex is right.

Answer (score 1):

You selector is wrong

```
 jQuery(document).ready(
     function() {
         jQuery("input.watermarkon").click(function(event) {
             jQuery(this).removeClass("watermarkon").addClass("watermarkoff");

         });
     }
 );
```

Comment: jQuery does support class selectors without tag names, so the selector ".watermarkon" is not wrong.

Comment: @Reinis - The OP isn't using `".watermarkon"` though, he's using a descendant selector for `<input>`.

Comment: @Reinis: 1.jquery does support class selectors without tag names. 2. I did not use one.

Answer (score 1):

Since the class is on the textbox directly, your CSS selectors should have the class on `input`, not having an `<input>` element as a child, so change them to this:

```
input.watermarkon
//and...
input.watermarkoff
```

And a bit more simplified jQuery to match:

```
jQuery("input.watermarkon").bind("blur focus", function() {
  jQuery(this).toggleClass("watermarkon watermarkoff");
});
```

Rather than a click, you typically want to change the watermark styling on `focus` and `blur` (with additional checks, depending on what you're after).  This will change the class to `watermarkoff` when focusing, and restore `watermarkon` when blurring using [`.toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) to swap the classes.

Comment: Yeah, and +1 for Nick again for his slick solution :)

Answer (score 0):

With the selector `.watermarkon input`you try to select all input elements inside another element that has the class `watermarkon`.

Also, if you remove the class `watermarkon` then you are not able to select the element again with a selector that includes `.watermarkon`.

So try to do it like this:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="watermark"/>
```

CSS:

```
.watermark {
    background-image: url('../forms/images/TypeNameWatermark.png'); 
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('input').click(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('watermark');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your CSS and jQuery, this is what you want to be doing:

```
 jQuery(document).ready(
     function() {
         jQuery(".watermarkon input").click(function(event) {
             jQuery(this).parents('.watermarkon').removeClass("watermarkon").addClass("watermarkoff");

         });
     }
 );
```

The issue is that the `input` doesn't have `.watermarkon` or `.watermarkoff` in the stylesheet, and nothing displays as you expect it to.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone for their help, I'm new to JS and JQuery and don't understand objects and inheritances well yet. I looked at all answers and tried a number of things. In my particular app, we have to use . input as I am working with custom programmed asp.net controls and if the "input" is missing, the CSS won't work on text boxes.

The code I ended up using was:

```
     jQuery(document).ready(
         function() {
             jQuery('.watermarkon').click(function(event) {
             jQuery(this).removeClass('watermarkon').addClass('watermarkoff');
             });
         }
     );
```

And I think it actually worked because of fixing my mis=use of double vs single quotes in the original code?

Thanks again for all of the replies!